# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDConfiguration in xcode

Tags: objective-c

I'm in insert the Firebase sdk and Googlesignin sdk also.
the google configuration does'nt be worked.
im using the objectiveC language using Stroyborad.
below the error will be showing on the screen.
Error
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_GIDConfiguration.

i try the to put the google configuration code in firebase website.
but the GIDCongiuration does'nt be worked.